# Change name of libGDX DesktopLauncher in mac OSX menu bar

Tags: java, macos, libgdx

I want to change the name of the menu bar items when launching my libGDX game from OSX

[image: Example of how it is now]

I tried changing the title in the DesktopLauncher config but this only changes the window title, not the menu bar. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the name of your `DesktopLauncher.java` class (and file).

Comment: How do I include spaces? Apple requires for the name to match the App Store name.

Comment: The name in appstore would not be the name that you see on the bar I guess... I've never exported app to appstore but in google play you are specyfing app name during export - I guess that here will be the same

Comment: Apple rejected my app due to the App Store name not matching the installed name so I'm not if shortening will work. I'll try this and if my app gets accepted I'll accept this answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Put

```
System.setProperty("com.apple.mrj.application.apple.menu.about.name", "Your App Name");
```

as the first line in your DesktopLauncher's `main` method.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it. After bundling the jar into a .app, add this to your main Info.plist

```
<string>-Xdock:name=Name Of App</string>
```